# How can I use IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet) symbols in ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, context, linguistics

I want to use IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet) symbols in ConTeXt but don't know how to do it.

Please tell me how to do it, if there is a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IPA symbols are located in the [“IPA Extensions” Unicode block](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0250.pdf).  To use them, load a [font which has them](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/ipa_extensions/fontsupport.htm) and input them directly or using the code points.

```
\definefont
  [IPA]
  [file:Tinos-Regular.ttf]

\starttext

{\IPA /ˈlɑːtɛx/}

{\IPA
  \utfchar{"002F}% SOLIDUS
  \utfchar{"02C8}% MODIFIER LETTER VERTICAL LINE
  \utfchar{"006C}% LATIN SMALL LETTER L
  \utfchar{"0251}% LATIN SMALL LETTER ALPHA
  \utfchar{"02D0}% MODIFIER LETTER TRIANGULAR COLON
  \utfchar{"0074}% LATIN SMALL LETTER T
  \utfchar{"025B}% LATIN SMALL LETTER OPEN E
  \utfchar{"0078}% LATIN SMALL LETTER X
  \utfchar{"002F}% SOLIDUS
}

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you ever want to use `\utfchar` when you can just type the characters directly into the source?

Comment: @AlanMunn Sometimes putting it in directly can be very confusing in mixed script documents, e.g. a (U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A) vs. а (U+0430 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A).

Comment: I guess I would use a macro then to wrap it. But to each their own. :)

Comment: Off topic, but I, along with the people around me, have always read it /ˈleɪ.tɛx/ ;-)